# Is something wrong with my partitioning?

Tags: partitioning

[image]

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.. I wonder if I have done the partition right?

Comment: @user68186 thank you for your comment...this is my first time .i just want to make sure there was nothing wrong

Comment: @user68186 well thanx for the info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with this setup**

Without knowing what you will be using your laptop for and what programs you will install, it is hard to say if this partition scheme is right for you.

For most home use, I recommend a simple three partitions system:

1. `/` This is the system partition for the OS. As little as 30GB may be fine. If you think you will install a lot of software, or develop web pages, you may want more.
2. `/home` This is where all your personal files including data, music, movies, etc. will go. This will also contain your personal configurations.
3. `swap` this is needed by Ubuntu to run smoothly. It is used as virtual RAM. 2GB to 4GB may be fine. You may want to put double your physical RAM if you want to hybernate your laptop. Hybernate is disabled by default as it does not work in all systems.

I don't have any use for a separate `/opt` partition. But, if you install a lot of software manually, this may be useful. If you decide to get rid of it, you may allocate this space either to `/`, where the `/opt` folder will be. Or you can allocate it to `/home`.

I also don't find it useful to have the two `drive_1` and `drive_2` partitions. I would allocate that space to `/home`.

However, these are personal preferences. Other people will tell you other things.

Hope his helps